# Wire version doesn't support for nodejs in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

ConfigurationError: Server at xxxxx:27017 reports wire version 0, but this version of nodejs requires at least 2 (MongoDB 2.6).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue using Linux subsystem for Windows and Nodejs mongoose v5.0.7.

I solved the issue by upgrading my MongoDB to v3.6.3 following the instructions on their documentation page. [Install docs here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried this way,but it didn't work, need to downgrade the nodejs drive version

Comment: @user3802625 How did you fix this then? Which version of mongodb npm package did you use to fix this?